Reset a variable when iterating over a for loop R Markdown
I have an .Rmd report that I loop over a variable to get the report to export one report per variable in the dataset. As part of my report structure, I have an incremental function to label the tables I'm generating in the report. Each individual report should start with Table 1 and iterate from there for each table. This works correctly when I just knit the .Rmd itself. But when I use an .R script to loop over the .Rmd script, the iteration doesn't reset back to one between loops.
So, the first report that kicks out starts the table captions at "Table 1" and then iterates through to "Table 4". The second report that kicks out from the loop starts at "Table 5" and then iterates from there and so on. I need each report to start the captions at "Table 1".
I'll try to include a MWE below, but my report is heavily reliant on a package I developed to make these reports match the organizational style guide. The first section of the below code chunks is a relevant chunk of my developed package, modified for inclusion here.
Required Package Exported Functions
## Part of the org package, but included here for replication. 
## These functions are exported for use in the package.

# Simple incremental function for labeling tables/plots/figures
increment <- function(init) function() { init <<- init + 1; init }

#Assigning new count functions
plotcount <- increment(0)
tablecount <- increment(0)
figurecount <- increment(0)

# Table/plot/figure caption function
caption <- function(caption, type) {
  if (type == "plots") {
    paste0("Plot ",plotcount(),". ",caption)
  } else if (type == "tables") {
    paste0("Table ",tablecount(),". ",caption)
  } else if (type == "figures") {
    paste0("Figure ",figurecount(),". ",caption)
  } else {paste0("Please choose a type from 'plots', 'tables', and 'figures'.")}
}

.Rmd and MWE data
## .Rmd relevant bits and MWE data
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: 'r Sys.Date()'
output: 
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: lualatex
params:
  primarygroup: i
---

``` {r setup, include=FALSE}
# knitr chunk options
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  echo = FALSE
)

# Reset increment
## This was a test, which failed.. Not sure what to do.
increment(0)

## Required Packages for Document
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)
library(scales)
```
``` {r data-creation}
p1 <- tibble(
  Itinerary = c(100, 101, 102, 103, 104),
  PrimaryGroup = c("Contractor 1", "Contractor 1", "Contractor 2", "Contractor 2", "Contractor 3"),
  Location = c("Loc 1", "Loc 2", "Loc 1", "Loc 2", "Loc 2"),
  ProblemDays = c(3, 5, 4, 3, 5),
  Fine = c(150, 250, 200, 150, 250)
)

p2 <- tibble(
  Itinerary = c(200, 201, 202, 203, 204),
  PrimaryGroup = c("Contractor 1", "Contractor 1", "Contractor 1", "Contractor 1", "Contractor 2"),
  ProblemDays = c(3, 5, 4, 3, 5),
  Fine = c(150, 250, 200, 150, 250)
)
```
# Problem 1
``` {r p1-table}
p1 %>%
  filter(PrimaryGroup == params$primarygroup) %>%
  mutate(Fine = dollar_format()(Fine)) %>%
  kable(
    booktabs = TRUE,
    align = "cllcc",
    linesep = ""
  )
```
`r caption("Table showing Problem 1 events.","tables")`

# Problem 2
``` {r p2-table}
p2 %>%
  filter(PrimaryGroup == params$primarygroup) %>%
  mutate(Fine = dollar_format()(Fine)) %>%
  kable(
    booktabs = TRUE,
    align = "clcc",
    linesep = ""
  )
```
`r caption("Table showing Problem 2 events.","tables")`

.R script to loop over PrimaryGroup values
## ReportLoop.R to run the .Rmd file
filedate <- format(Sys.Date(), "%Y%m%d")

# Identify primarygroups
primarygroup <- tibble(
  PrimaryGroup = c("Contractor 1", "Contractor 2", "Contractor 3")
)

# Run fines.Rmd for each service provider
for (i in unique(primarygroup$PrimaryGroup)) {
  rmarkdown::render(input = "fines/fines.Rmd",
                    params = list(primarygroup = i),
                    output_file = paste0(filedate, "_", i, "_fines.pdf"))
}

If I manually knit the fines.Rmd file and iterate on each primarygroup value, the caption function correctly starts counting at "Table 1." But if I run the ReportLoop.R script, the function iterates incorrectly as described above. I tried exporting the increment() function [it wasn't originally exported, but I wanted to test this] and then adding increment(0) to the beginning of the .Rmd document, but that didn't fix the issue.
Is there some other way I can make this work? Either by modifying the package, the fines.Rmd markdown file, or the reportloop.R for loop script?

You could, for example, use the following definition:
increment <- function (init) {
  self <- environment()
  value <- init

  function (set) {
    if (missing(set)) {
      self$value <- value + 1
      value
    } else {
      self$value <- set
    }
  }
}

(I’ve also renamed the counter variable to make it more readable.)
Now you can reset the counters by passing a new start value to it:
plotcount <- increment(0)

plotcount() # 1
plotcount() # 2
plotcount() # 3
plotcount(0)
plotcount() # 1


This works if the caption function is defined as part of the .Rmd file, but not when the caption function is defined in the package itself which is how it's currently set up.  Any thoughts on other things to try?

It should definitely still work. You would need to export the relevant functions though. But a much cleaner solution would be to run each invokation of rmarkdown::render() in its own process, or at least to unload your package inside the loop before each invocation, via unloadNamespace().

Including unloadNamespace() in the for loop worked great. I couldn't get the other solution to work since plotcount couldn't be exported as defined. Thanks for the help!

Why create self? (just curious) Instead of directly "value <- init" and "<<-" in function?

@s_baldur <- assignment on its own wouldn’t work, and <<- is hugely problematic and I have basically banned its use from any code base I am working on because it is too error-prone: a single typo and suddenly you are assigning into the global environment instead of the environment you intended. target$x <- value makes it explicit into which environment you are assigning.
